# How can I compare the standard deviation of the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, forecasting, standard-deviation, model-comparison

How can I compare the standard deviation of the dependent variable?

Is a lower number better between regressions, i.e. in one model its 0.2 does this mean it the dependent variable is more predictable compared to a model where it is 0.5.

Comment: Why are you comparing residual SE between models? What is your goal?

Comment: I am comparing models that do ao similar thing (forecasting) but some Rsquareds are much higher in some models and I want to know the reason for this

Comment: If you want to compare quality of predictions then use a metric designed for this, for ex. RMSE. $R^2$ is not a good measure for this.

Comment: yes but say I am trying to forecast variable A and get an r-squared of 80, and for variable B I get an r-squared of 1%, can I say this change is due to the standard deviation of the dependent variable

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: your comments have been (i) insightful, (ii) extremely helpful, (iii) I can see they have taken you a considerable amount of time (iv) I am now on the right track and (v) why dont you make this an answer (I am sure it will receive manu upvotes. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: Is that sarcasm?

Comment: @user2974951 no!

Comment: @user2974951 As $R^2$ is a transformation of the $RMSE$, $R^2 = 1-\dfrac{n\times RMSE^2}{\sum (y_i - \bar y)^2}$, why do you say to prefer $RMSE$ over $R^2?$